# Is there any way to find all of the Sep/Oct 2016 DDos accounts?

Tags: accounts, hardforks

[This EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-161.md) allowed for the cleaning up of the nearly 20 million DDos accounts created during the September/October 2016 DDos attack. The solution had two parts: (1) the node code had to be changed to delete 'dead' accounts, but only if those accounts were subsequently 'touched', and (2) someone (the Etereum foundation) had to generate transactions that 'touched' those accounts (which were dead) so they would get deleted.

My understanding is that Vitalik ran some sort of off-chain script that sent zero ether to all 20 million accounts (and that by doing this, the accounts got deleted), but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Is there any way to get a listing of all 20 million accounts that were 'touched'?

Comment: Are you sure that these 20 mio addresses have been cleaned up? I queried the addresses in Jan 2021 on Google Big Query and found more than 24 mio addresses without activity. Are the 20 mio DDOS addresses included in these 24 mio addresses or are the 24 mio addresses new inactive ones?

Comment: I think my original wording was incorrect. You can't 'clean up' the history of those addresses having been created. When I said 'cleaned up' I should have said 'their state was removed.' The transactions and receipts of the creation during the DDOS is still on the chain. What Vitalik did, after the EIP went into effect, was send transactions that touched those addresses. The EIP, seeing them as dust accounts, then 'removed' them from the state. Now, it's "as if" they never existed, but their brief existence is still in the history.